# SQL Search string from a column in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This may have been been asked before but I am not sure how to search for it.
I want to find if the string in Column2 is a part of , or not used at all in Column1

```
Column1       | Column2
=======================
ABCDE + JKL   |     XC
XC - PQ       |      A   
XYZ + A       |     C
AC  + PQ      |     MA
```

So the result for column2 never used in column 1 would be

```
C
MA
```

Comment: MS SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like another regex expressions task with no regex allowed.

Assuming you have expressions containing only letters, you can write the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE Expressions
(
    Column1 varchar(20),
    Column2 varchar(20)
)

INSERT Expressions VALUES
('ABCDE + JKL', 'XC'),
('XC - PQ', 'A'),
('XYZ + A', 'C'),
('AC  + PQ', 'MA'),
('A+CF', 'ZZ'),
('BB+ZZ+CF', 'YY')

SELECT E1.Column2
FROM Expressions E1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Expressions E2
    WHERE E1.Column2=E2.Column1 --Exact match
       OR PATINDEX(E1.Column2+'[^A-Z]%', E2.Column1) <> 0 --Starts with
       OR PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]'+E1.Column2, E2.Column1) <> 0 --Ends with
       OR PATINDEX('%[^A-Z]'+E1.Column2+'[^A-Z]%', E2.Column1) <> 0 --In the middle
)
```

It returns:

```
Column2
-------
C
MA
YY
```

Answer (score 3):

The description of the problem talks about the string in `column2`.  YOu can do this with some variation on `like`.  In most databases, some variation of:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.column1 not like '%' || t.column2 || '%';
```

Some databases spell `||` as `+` or even `concat()`, but the idea is the same.

However, I'm not sure what the sample data is doing.  In no case is the string in `column2` in `column1`.

Comment: I am using MS SQL Server 2014. The strings in Column 2 can be present in any row. XC from the first record is present in row 2 column 1. A is present in row 3. C and MA are not present in any rows.