# What is wrong with my SQL syntax for searching a String in a column based on the String from another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, wildcard

I am using `SQL Server 2014` and I have the following `T-SQL` query:

```
USE [MyDatabase]

SELECT [FirstName], [Email]

FROM [t1]

WHERE [Email] like '%'  + [FirstName] +  '%'
```

I would like to extract all records where [FirstName] appears in the [Email]. However, my query is not giving me the expected output.

I have written my "WHERE" filter based on an answer by Gordon Linoff in the following question:

[SQL Search string from a column in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38577573/sql-search-string-from-a-column-in-another-column)

I feel I am missing something but I just can't figure where I am going wrong.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Sample:**

```
FirstName         Email
Michelle          michelle.jones@noemail.com
```

Comment: Sample data and expected results are highly welcome

Comment: It seems you have the query reversed. In its current form, it returns the data where the first name containst the email, not the other way around.

Comment: You are searching for the opposite!

Comment: I've removed the Regex tag, as the above it *not* Regex, and nor does SQL Server support it (natively).

Comment: because you are asking for 'fred' like '%fred.bloggs@gmail.com%'

Comment: @Alejandro Yes you are right. I messed up that part. I have now corrected it in my question. However, I am still not getting the expected results.

Comment: @Cato Thanks. I have corrected same in my question. Still not getting the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to extract all records where [FirstName] appears in the [Email].

If so, then this:

```
WHERE [FirstName]  like '%'  + [Email] +  '%'
```

Looks backwards to me, and you really want this:

```
WHERE [Email]  like '%'  + [FirstName] +  '%'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t.[FirstName], t.[Email]
FROM t1 AS t
WHERE CHARINDEX(t.[FirstName], t.[Email]) > 0
```

Returns 0 if not found.
Returns first index if found. For example:

```
FirstName: foo
Email: foo@bar.com
```

will return 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this

```
SELECT [FirstName], [Email]

FROM [t1]

WHERE [Email] like '%' || [FirstName]  || '%'
```